# Parse Live Query handling Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, server, real-time

I'm using parse live query for realtime communication and works for every types of events, but my problem is it happens that the server disconnect or internet connection is down so how can i handle error block ?
I try to make error block in subscription as an event

```
.handleError(<#T##handler: (PFQuery<Blocks>, Error) -> Void##(PFQuery<Blocks>, Error) -> Void#>)
```

but without success, I want to capture the error which is logged

```
2018-02-21 22:14:55.050543+0100 Youz[2095:1024917] TCP Conn 0x106d13f40 
Failed : error 0:50 [50]
2018-02-21 22:14:55.051443+0100 Youz[2095:1024955] ParseLiveQuery: 
WebSocket did disconnect with error: Optional(Error 
Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=50 "Network is down" UserInfo=
{_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})
2018-02-21 22:14:55.057945+0100 Youz[2095:1024917] [] 
nw_connection_get_connected_socket 971 Connection has no connected 
handler
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture Websocket Events with NSNotificationCenter.

just like this.

-(void) OnWebsocketConnected : (NSNotification *) noti {

```
DLogInfo(@"OnWebsocketConnected, noti= %@", noti);
```

}

-(void) OnWebsocketDisconnected : (NSNotification *) noti {

```
DLogInfo(@"OnWebsocketDisconnected, noti= %@", noti);

// can't recover lost data on Parse live query, we need to query manually.
```

}

-(void) OnWebsocketError : (NSNotification *) noti {

```
DLogInfo(@"OnWebsocketError, noti= %@", noti);
```

}

-(void) initializer {

......

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(OnWebsocketConnected:) name:@"WebsocketDidConnectNotification" object:nil];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(OnWebsocketDisconnected:) name:@"WebsocketDidDisconnectNotification" object:nil];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(OnWebsocketError:) name:@"WebsocketDisconnectionErrorKeyName" object:nil];

.......

}